# Docker-compose throws java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have a problem about running query module regarding CQRS in Spring Boot.

I cannot connect database with the app.

Here is docker-compose.yml of account.query shown below

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    image: 'account-query:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/bankAccount?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      - server.port=5001
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=root
      - spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
    networks:
      - bankQuery

  database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - bankQuery
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10


networks:
  bankQuery:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

When I run this file through docker-compose --build, I get this issue.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'bankAccount'
```

How can I fix it?

Here is the link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/cqrs-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` to the datasource url, the issue disaapeared.

Here is the enviromental variable of this part shown below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/bankAccount?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the database: `MYSQL_DATABASE: bankAccount`

```
database:
  container_name: mysql-database
  image: 'mysql:latest'
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: bankAccount
  volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  networks:
    - bankQuery
  healthcheck:
    test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
    timeout: 20s
    retries: 10
```